# nodenv install returns node-build: TMPDIR is set to a non-accessible location

Tags: node.js

when I try and run `nodenv install x.x.x` it returns an error

```
node-build: TMPDIR=/var/folders/r6/582734pd05vctn829j19qzbh0000gn/T is set to a non-accessible location
```

I have tried installing installing `nodenv` using `brew install nodenv` and `git clone https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv.git ~/.nodenv` and both return the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tldr:** delete your node modules before running yarn install

Someone has named a node module `touch` that conflicts with the linux command of the same name. It causes the `node-build` installer to fail when testing the temp directory.

```
# Check if TMPDIR is accessible and can hold executables.
tmp_executable="${TMP}/node-build-test.$$"
noexec=""
if mkdir -p "$TMP" && touch "$tmp_executable" 2>/dev/null; then
  cat > "$tmp_executable" <<-EOF
    #!${BASH}
    exit 0
    EOF
  chmod +x "$tmp_executable"
else
  echo "node-build: TMPDIR=$TMP is set to a non-accessible location" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```